# Nuxt Linking CSS Files in Head property from assets issue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

I am trying to link my css files by using head property of nuxt in only one specific page like this:

```js
  head: {
    link: [
      {rel: 'stylesheet', href: require('~/assets/css/font.css')},
      {rel: 'stylesheet', href: require('~/assets/css/style.css')},
    ]
}
```

After doing this when I load my page Everything is fine but I see this Error at Console
**GET http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object] net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)**

and when I looked at source I saw that CSS Files were linked this way :

```html
<link data-n-head="ssr" rel="stylesheet" href="[object Object]">
<link data-n-head="ssr" rel="stylesheet" href="[object Object]">
```

I need to import my CSS filed this way but I still have this problem, How can I solve this ?

Comment: remove require ... use like this {rel: 'stylesheet', href: '~/assets/css/font.css'},

Comment: If I remove require styles wouldn't be added properly
It doesn't works that way

Comment: it will work ... is ur assets and nuxt cofig in same folder?

Comment: I tried that before posting this issue here, if I remove require it will be linked this way : <link href="~/assets/css/font.css"> and it doesn't work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to call an asset in the head property you have to add/move it to the `/static` folder, which is publicly accessible, and then refer to it explicitly. This method doesn't minify the file(s).

```js
head: {
  link: [
    {rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', href: '/css/font.css'},
    {rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', href: '/css/style.css'}
  ]
}
```

Alternatively, you can leave it where it is and import it via `@import` between the `<style>` tags of the `.vue` file, without the initial forward slash.

```html
<style scoped>
  @import url('~assets/css/font.css');
  @import url('~assets/css/style.css');
</style>
```

[Source01](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/assets#webpack) | [Source02](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/pr_import_rule.asp)

Comment: For Nuxt3 its `/public` folder